# How to handle class imbalance with H2O AutoML

Tags: classification, h2o, automl

I'm using H2O AutoML to do binary classification, and the classes are imbalanced.

I've set `balance_classes = TRUE` and `max_after_balance_size = 100` in `h2o.automl()` function to oversample the minority class. However, the metric "area under the Precision-Recall curve (AUCPR)" of the leader model is not very good, ~ 0.10.

May I ask, are there any tips (e.g., preprocessing steps, parameter setting in `h2o.automl()`) to handle the class imbalance problem with H2O AutoML?

Your kind guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend specifying `stopping_metric = "AUCPR"` to optimize for AUCPR and `sort_metric = "AUCPR"` to let AutoML know that the leader model should be the one with the best AUCPR (otherwise it would use AUC by default).

If your data is small enough, you might be able to use libraries like [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.org/) in python or [themis](https://themis.tidymodels.org/) in R to do some preprocessing like SMOTE, removing Tomek links etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tomas!

I've set `stopping_metric = "AUCPR"` and it indeed improved the AUCPR from 0.1 to 0.3.

I also tried the `themis` package to use different oversample/downsample methods (e.g., SMOTE, ROSE, Tomek). However, the AUCPR didn't improve much further, sometimes even worse. May I ask: given the prevalence of minority class in my data is 0.05, whether an AUCPR of 0.3 is acceptable? Does it have to be close to 1?

Comment: Or, can I use other metrics to evaluate the model handling imbalanced data, such as AUC or logloss?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the use-case but AUCPR 0.3 seems low. Depending on your use-case you can guess the costs of individual errors (false positives vs false negatives, low precision vs low recall etc.) and use `weight_column` to do the balancing/weighing manually. 

AUCPR shows you the overall performance for the model so it's good for comparing different models but in production you often care about what errors are made (FP vs FN), this can be inspected using [confusion matrix](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#confusion-matrix).